# Can I use a scoped enum for C++ tag dispatch with templates?

Tags: c++, templates, generic-programming

Template newbie here. I'm experimenting with the following code:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

enum class Thread
{
    MAIN, HELPER
};

template<typename T>
int f()
{
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<T, Thread::MAIN>);
    return 3;
}

int main()
{
    f<Thread::MAIN>();
}
```

In words, I want to raise a compile-time assert if the function is not called from the main thread. Apparently the compiler doesn't accept an enumerator as template argument, yelling `invalid explicitly-specified argument for template parameter 'T'`.

I know I could use two structs as tags: `struct ThreadMain` and `struct ThreadHelper`. Unfortunately the enum cass is already used everywhere in my project and I'd prefer to avoid duplicates. How can I reuse the existing enum class for this purpose?

Comment: Your template takes a *type*.  `std::is_same_v` compares *types*.  `Thread` is a *type*. But `Thread::MAIN` and `Thread::HELPER` are not *types*, they are *values* of type `Thread`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your existing code is close.  Instead of using `typename`, you can just use the `enum class` name directly, as a *non-type template parameter*, like this:

```
template<Thread T>
int f()
{
    static_assert(T == Thread::MAIN);
    return 3;
}
```

You have to change the `static_assert` as well.

Comment: +1, However it would be better to use `N` for a *non-type* (value) template parameter like a common style with e.g. `template<int N>`. `T` parameter name may inaccurately suggest that this is a **T**ype parameter whereas it is not. Especially that his is not typical `enum` underlying type.

Comment: @bloody "it would be better" that's just an opinion, not a rule or guideline.

Comment: @JHBonarius Exactly it is, so what?