# A template class that only accepts enum type arguments?

Tags: c++, c++11

Given this pseudo stub class:

```
template<class T>
MyClass
{
 std::map<T,std::string> mContents;
};
```

Is there a way to only allow `T` to be an enum type? I was trying to understand what was discussed in this question and linked pages, whether I can use `std::enable_if`with `std::is_enum` but I can't get my head round it easily to see if it translates to my case ([Template specialization for enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619993/template-specialization-for-enum))

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use a scoped enum for C++ tag dispatch with templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65618471/can-i-use-a-scoped-enum-for-c-tag-dispatch-with-templates)

Comment: "force" in the sense of `static_assert(std::is_enum<T>::value, "not an enum");`?

Comment: @JHBonarius should broadly the same question about a template function and template class be viewed as duplicates? If yes, then it is a dupe - thanks

Comment: Although being "SFINAE-friendly" via using C++20 constraints or `enable_if`, etc. is more important for function templates than for class templates. It can still make a difference for a class template, but it's much less common for other template code to detect/depend on whether a class template specialization is valid.

Answer (score 8):

You don't need any `enable_if` tricks. All you need is a `static_assert`:

```
template<class T>
class MyClass
{
  // pre-C++17:
  static_assert(std::is_enum<T>::value, "template argument must be enum");
  // C++17
  static_assert(std::is_enum_v<T>);
  std::map<T,std::string> mContents;
};
```

In C++20, you can use a constraint instead.

Comment: I haven't come across that before, thanks

Comment: @dyp C++Reference says it's even C++17. Made an edit.

Comment: Right, `is_enum_v` and `static_assert` with one expression are C++17. The C++20 constraint could look like `template <class T> requires std::is_enum_v<T> class MyClass`...

Comment: We're in an interesting time of evolution for templates. My prediction: Over the next few C++ revisions templates will become much easier to understand and use. That or gain sentience.

Comment: You say "don't need" `enable_if` but the example Marek posts is not any more complex - is there a reason why one is preferable to the other?

Comment: @Mr.Boy I would prefer `static_assert` here, when possible. Static assert shows intent better, as it will always be a hard error while `enable_if` can also be used for SFINAE. It also gives you the option to specify a clear and understandable compile error instead of the pages of template errors generated by a failed instatiation with `enable_if`.

Comment: @Mr.Boy First, `enable_if` as in Marek's answer is a misuse, because it doesn't actually disable a specialization. Also, compare the error messages in the fail case for the two approaches and you'll see a massive difference.

Comment: Thanks for that - it might be worth adding that to the answer (almost verbatim)

Answer (score 4):

https://godbolt.org/z/4bvdrb

```cpp
template<class T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_enum_v<T>>>
class MyClass
{
    std::map<T,std::string> mContents;
};
```